# google play warns about added permission 'android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG'

Tags: android

I've just tried to submit a new version of my app without any changes in the permissions. However, google play's upload apk tells me that I've added the permission 'android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG', which I didn't. These are currently my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Any ideas what the reason could be for this? (I don't want to add a new permission, my users don't like that very much)

Comment: What does your `<uses-sdk>` element look like?

Comment: I currenty have (didn't touch that either): <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

Comment: Hmmm... well, I'm not aware that `READ_CALL_LOG` was ever grandfathered in, and I'd be stunned if it were grandfathered in for a `minSdkVersion` of 8. Try running the `aapt dump badging` commmand on your APK. If that reports that you have requested `READ_CALL_LOG`, there's definitely something afoot in the APK itself. If `aapt dump badging` does not show `READ_CALL_LOG`, then the problem is perhaps on Google's side with the Play Store servers.

Comment: I think you're right that this might be caused by Google Play changes. I removed the permission 'android.permission.READ_CONTACTS' and READ_CALL_LOG no longer appeared. I tried your suggestion 'aapt dump badging' and READ_CALL_LOG never appears. Thanks for pointing out this tool!

Comment: @alvi Do you have the latest Android SDK Tools? And the message about `android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG` appears way below the permission we explicit set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Which led to that in `aapt dump badging`:

```
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG','targetSdkVersion < 16 and requested READ_CONTACTS'
```

Then I changed it to that:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Now the implied permission went away.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that changing the targetSdkVersion has lots of side effects (both documented and not documented). You should not be suddenly forced like this, it takes good planning.

I wonder which component is responsible for this change, and if I can rollback the "update" for now?

Comment: True that is, to me, unfortunately, this seems to be a change on the Google side. You may try to upload an 'old' APK, and I bet it will still warn you about the implied permission. Because none of us really changed our local toolchain, did we?

Comment: By the way I took the plunge and uploaded my app with the added but not really added permission. I was happy to see that on google play, the new permission did not appear and I did not get a warning, i.e. I didn't have to manually upgrade.

Comment: It should be noted that any library (such as Google Play Services) that does NOT specify a targetSDKVersion will cause this permission to be erroneously added. You MUST set the targetSDKVersion on every library your app uses to be >=16

Comment: How do you workaround this when using Gradle/Maven libraries? You can't edit them and the manifest merger doesn't work very well in this case...

Comment: I found the explanation for the implied permission in app/build/outputs/apk/manifest-merger-release-report.txt

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. My app has :

```
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, INTERNET, and BROADCAST_STICKY
```

but when I upload the apk to google play I get 6 permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I changed the min and target sdk versions from 3 to 4 and the extra permissions went away.

Answer (score 0):

My "aapt dump badging" tells that READ_CALL_LOG is implied by READ_CONTACTS.

uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG','targetSdkVersion < 16 and requested READ_CONTACTS'

Still, this appears to have been changed at some time. All my previous version (last 2 weeks ago) of the same app don't imply that permission, although I did not change any permissions for months.

Comment: See my answer below. The message states: `targetSdkVersion < 16`. When leaving `minSdkVersion` the same, you should be able to increase `targetSdkVersion` to at least `16` without other impact, right?

Answer (score 0):

Change the targetSdkVersion to 16 will cause the menu key disappeared on the devices > 4.0.
For I add the sherlock project in the app.

Answer (score 0):

The doc already mentions this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html